# When to compile files together and when to use a library

Tags: c, linker

Search didn't turn anything up.

If I have a file main.c and a pair aux.h and aux.c for useful functions when should I just compile main.c and aux.c together and when should I make a library out of aux (like aux.a).

Comment: To all the people down-voting this question, please stop. It's a very reasonable question for a novice programmer to ask, and contrary to what "close" votes suggest, it has a correct and not purely opinion based answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when should I just compile main.c and aux.c together and when should I make a library out of aux (like aux.a).

When you have a *single* utility file, putting it into a library buys you *nothing*. It's only when you have a few separate files, which provide some common, but related functionality that it starts to make sense to put them into an archive (or shared) library.

You actually have 3 choices in building your program:

1. Compile and link everything together in a single step:

   `gcc -o main main.c aux.c`
2. Write a proper `Makefile`. That will result in separate compilation:

   `gcc -c main.c`
   `gcc -c aux.c`
   `gcc -o main main.o aux.o`
3. Write a `Makefile` that uses the library. This will also result in separate compilation, something like:

   `gcc -c main.c`
   `gcc -c aux.c`
   `ar cru libaux.a aux.o`
   `gcc -o main main.o -laux`

For anything other than the smallest toy program, you should at least do #2, because doing so eliminates the time wasted recompiling `aux.c` or `main.c` when either didn't change, while still ensuring that your program is built correctly.

As I said, doing #3 for a *single* file buys nothing at all (you just perform a few unnecessary steps).

Using a library is advised when:

1. You have several different programs that you build, and
2. You have several related utility files, some (but not all) of which are used in these programs.

Consider the case where you have `prog1`, `prog2` and `prog3`, and `aux1.c`, `aux2.c` and `aux3.c` utility files. Suppose that `prog1` uses code from `aux1.c` and `aux2.c`, `prog2` uses code from `aux1.c` and `aux3.c`, and `prog3` uses code from all `aux*.c` files.

In that situation, using case #2, you will have to write `Makefile` that looks something like this:

```
prog1: main1.o aux1.o aux2.o
prog2: main2.o aux1.o aux3.o
prog3: main3.o aux1.o aux2.o aux3.o
```

That's (potentially) a lot of management.

Compare to the `Makefile` that uses case #3 (i.e. a library):

```
prog1: main1.o libaux.a
prog2: main2.o libaux.a
prog3: main3.o libaux.a
```

Simpler, isn't it?

Also consider what happens if `main1.c` *changes*, and starts to use `aux3.o` as well. In case #2, you would have to adjust your `Makefile`, but in case #3 your `Makefile` is already correct!

Comment: Thanks very much for the in-depth answer! That clears all the questions for me!

Answer (score 1):

if the aux.c is used frequently in many other places，you could consider to make it a static or dynamic library. 
if it's just a one time run toy program，nothing matters